# React-express: GET Routes do not work from href but POST routes work from Form submissions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, url, routes

I am trying to configure routing with React without delving into React Router. I have a react client app and an express server app separate. Essentially the register and login POST routes work perfectly fine, but in order to get them to run they are ran by submitting a form like this:
`<form className="loginform" refs='loginform' method="POST" action="/users/login" novalidate="novalidate">`
They work fine. But using a normal href does not activate my /logout GET route. It is not because it is the wrong address, on express on the server side I have

```
const users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users/', users);
```

Below is the problematic href link in a React component I have set up in a client side.

```
<div className="userquickdash row">
  <div className="usernamedash">{props.username}</div>
  <div className="logout"><a href="/users/logout">logout</a>
 </div>
```

Below is the '/logout' route on the server that I cannot seem to get working. The main '/' route fires instead even when it directs to http://localhost:3000/users/logout in the browser. When I replace "/logout" with "*" that is the only way I can get that specific route to work.

```
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    console.log('heylogoutrouteworks');
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('mainroute');
    User.find()
        .then(User => res.json(User))
});
```

These are the POST routes that are working fine when fired from a form submission.

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
        User.authenticate(req.body.email, req.body.password, function (error, user) {
            console.log(user);
            if (error || !user) {
                var err = new Error('Wrong email or password');
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
            } else {
                req.session.userId = user._id;
                req.session.username = user.username;
                return res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    } else {
        var err = new Error('Email and password are required');
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
    }
});

// REGISTER
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body.username && req.body.regemail && req.body.regpassword && req.body.confirmPassword) {

        // confirm that user typed same password twice
        if (req.body.regpassword !== req.body.confirmPassword) {
            var err = new Error('Passwords do not match');
            err.status = 400;
            err.type = 'sign in error';
            return next(err);
        } 

        // create obj with form input
        var userData = {
            email: req.body.regemail,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.regpassword,
            watching: '',

        };

        // use schema's 'create' method to insert document into Mongo
        User.create(userData, function (error, user) {
            if (error) {
                return next(error);
            } else {
                console.log(user);
                req.session.userId = user._id;
                req.session.username = user.username;
                return res.redirect('/');
            }
        });

    } else {
        var err = new Error('All fields required for account registration');
        err.status = 400;
        return next(err);
    }
});
```

The help is appreciated.

Comment: Not enough code to determine what's going on. Please post a link to a remote repository that contains all of the code.

Comment: Or, install `npm i -S morgan` (a logging framework) and check your console to see all server requests. If you see `GET /users/logout 404` or `GET /users/logout 201` and it's not hitting your desired route, then your routes aren't configured properly.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I installed morgan. Seems there is a 304 status. Im going to look into that. If I have any more issues I will upload the repo.

Comment: 304 means it hit a route but nothing was changed. So it's seeing a route, but not the correct route.My guess is that one of your routes is catching it before it's hitting the correct route.

Comment: I think I just need to improve my understanding of React. I had a fetch request which was making a GET request to '/', so essentially what you said. I didnt realize that every href link had to be some type of fetch request. But also I could just make a function for that.

Comment: I'd highly recommend learning react-router. This way you can separate your front-end routes from your back-end routes. In the long run, it'll make your life easier. OR,  if you're dead set on not using react-router, learn server-side rendering.